# arithmetic on simple pandas data frame (time series)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, math, time, series

I am having a pandas data frame called dj.

Its index column is a series of days, from 01/01/2021 to 01/01/2025.
I am trying to create a time series of historical flow concatenated with forecasted flow.

I am very beginner in python and though I could do simple arithmetic on columns, i.e adding 2 columns together or doing subtraction would give me a new column containing for each day the sum of the daily value of the other columns. I thought I could also do simple operations such as multiplication or division.

See the part of the code that does not work and error that is returned

#dj is a panda dataframe

## below I am adding 4 columns that contain a fixed value similar for all days

## then I would like to do simple arithmetic on it but it does not work. I can add together a column with itself and it works but I can't add together  2 of the below columns if those are different columns, it would not return the expected new column.

```
    dj['Zee forecast'] = 40
    dj['FR forecast'] = 45
    dj['DE forecast'] = 100
    dj['NL forecast'] = 35
    dj['Conti forecast new'] = dj['Zee forecast'] - dj['FR forecast'] + dj['DE forecast'] + dj['NL forecast']
```

running the above returns an error

I have not tried a lot of things as I am not sure how to go about it.
Any documentation on how to manipulate pandas data frame would be useful if anyone has something to share